# python- deleting of elements from a list

Tags: python

```
name = list('ayushgupta')
>>> name
['a', 'y', 'u', 's', 'h', 'g', 'u', 'p', 't', 'a']
>>> name[5:5] = list('THE')
>>> name
['a', 'y', 'u', 's', 'h', 'T', 'H', 'E', 'g', 'u', 'p', 't', 'a']
>>> name[5:5] = []
>>> name
['a', 'y', 'u', 's', 'h', 'T', 'H', 'E', 'g', 'u', 'p', 't', 'a']
```

If I try to delete 'T', 'H', 'E' from name using name[5:5], it doesn't work. I know I can use name[5:8] to delete the same. Could anyone explain why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

You can change both the content and the length of a list by assigning to slice of the list. However, your slice is `name[5:5]`. Remember that *a slice does not include the ending index*. Thus, your slice starts at `name[5]` and continues to but does not include `name[5]`. In other words, your slice is *empty*.

In short, you are trying to delete a part of the list that already is empty. If you try an actual slice, such as `name[5:8]`, you will be more successful. To delete just one item, try `name[5:6]`. The length of slice `name[a:b]` is `b-a` (if `b` is greater than or equal to `a`), which is easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
>>> name[5:8] = []
>>> name
['a', 'y', 'u', 's', 'h', 'g', 'u', 'p', 't', 'a']
```

When you did, `name[5:5]=list('THE')`, `THE` got inserted into the list from 5th index to 5th index of list. When you are doing `name[5:5] = []`, you are not deleting anything, instead trying to insert empty `list`, and hence no change. For updating the items from list from 5 to 8 index, you have to do `name[5:8] = []`

OR, you may use `del` to delete content for the list as:

```
>>> del name[5:8]
>>> name
['a', 'y', 'u', 's', 'h', 'g', 'u', 'p', 't', 'a']
```

Comment: "*Could anyone explain why is it so?*". Well?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Was already on the way to update that, Check edit :)

Comment: Good. You should consider taking your time to give a full answer for first try. It can spare you some downvotes. I'm only telling you this because I've seen you show FGITW behaviour a lot, and I don't think this benefits the askers, nor the site. If you give an answer, make it good. You'll even get more rep like that in the long run.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I will follow your suggestion. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
    name[5:5]
```

means: element from the index `5` (inclusive) to `5` (**exclusive**)

So you have use something as

```
    name[4:5]
```

to select (by rather complicated way) element `name[4]`.